# Why does systemd-networkd start so late in the boot process? Question about systemd dependencies

Tags: systemd, systemd-networkd

I'm investigating whether I can improve the boot speed of my Gentoo Linux system which uses systemd. I've noticed that my onboard network cards (rtl8111g) take a long time to detect a carrier, but only attempt to do so once the interfaces are initialised by systemd-networkd. I'm trying to start that initialisation earlier in the boot process.

Network interfaces are initialised by `systemd-networkd.service` which depends on `network-pre.target`. The only service in `network-pre.target` is `nftables-restore.service`. Below are the outputs of `systemd-analyze critical-chain` and `systemd-analze plot`.

(`local-fs.target` awaiting the mounts is a separate issue that is awaiting a new systemd package).

Why does `systemd-networkd.service` start at the time it does? How do I find what it waited for?

```
The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.

planes.target @18.601s
└─multi-user.target @18.601s
  └─getty.target @18.601s
    └─getty@tty7.service @18.598s
      └─apache2.service @18.594s
        └─nss-lookup.target @18.590s
          └─pdns-recursor.service @17.790s +799ms
            └─network-online.target @17.750s
              └─ppp@aquiss.service @17.179s +570ms
                └─basic.target @8.851s
                  └─sockets.target @8.846s
                    └─systemd-journal-remote.socket @8.842s
                      └─sysinit.target @8.740s
                        └─systemd-timesyncd.service @8.364s +369ms
                          └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @8.113s +238ms
                            └─local-fs.target @8.103s
                              └─mnt-sdb3-snapshots.mount @3.073s +5.024s
                                └─systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-6e2797f3\x2dd0ab\x2d4aa1\x2db262\x2dc2395fd0626e.service @2.970s +54ms
                                  └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-6e2797f3\x2dd0ab\x2d4aa1\x2db262\x2dc2395fd0626e.device @2.888s
```

[image: Boot plot]

Comment: As far as I can see it starts right after mounting your storage which takes a very long time. You could definitely use an SSD. Your HDD is very slow.

Comment: Yes, agreed. The system boots on an SSD and the HDD volumes are mounted with `nofail`, which is broken in systemd-249.2. I'm waiting for the distribution to update to 249.4 where this is fixed and the mounts won't be waited for.

Comment: `systemd-networkd.service` doesn't start until after `network-pre.target` is reached.